# am trying to check if a value in a dictionary is an integer or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am trying to check if a value in a dictionary is an integer or not.

I have something like

```
d = {'number' : '1-', 'name' : 'A'}
```

am trying to see if the value  of number is an integer after removing the '-'

Code:

```
d['number'] = d['number'].replace('-','')
```

so now its showing me `d = {'number' : '1', 'name' : 'A'}`
here the value of number is again a string. But i want to check if the string is a number or an alphabet.

```
number can be of '12121' or 'rdrr'
```

How do I check if it has only digits ?

Comment: str.is_digits() method

Comment: `'12121'.isdigit()` returns `True`

Comment: `d['number'] = d['number'].replace('-', '', regex=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` functions. `isdigit()` returns "True" if all characters in the string are digits and `isalpha()` returns "True" if all characters in the string are alphabetic:

```
>>> d = {'number' : '1', 'name' : 'A'}
>>> d['number'].isdigit()
True
>>> d['number'].isalpha()
False
>>> d['name'].isdigit()
False
>>> d['name'].isalpha()
True
```

Comment: Can I write an else function if the if doesnt satisfy ? –

Comment: Of course! These functions return a boolean value so you can use them in an `if...elif...else...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re` module

```
 import re
 if re.match(r"\d+","12"): print('It is a number')
```

Comment: Can I write an else function if the if doesnt satisfy ?

Comment: yes just like you would normally do : `else: print('sorry not a number')`

Answer (score 0):

If you need both key and value:

```
d = {'number' : '1', 'name' : 'A'}

digits = {}
for key, value in d.items():
  if value.isdigit():
    digits[key] = value
```

If you need just key:

```
digits = [key for key, value in d.items() if value.isdigit()]
```

Result of :

```
print(digits)
```

for 1st solution:

```
{'number': '1'}
```

for 2nd solution:

```
['number']
```